# Ali is a great manager. He is/was a born leader

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, past-tense, present-tense, subject-verb-agreement

I'm having trouble with the following sentence:

---

> 1) Ali is a great manager. He **is** a born leader.
>
> 2)  Ali is a great manager. He **was** a born leader.

*I'd say that (1) is the right one since Ali is still alive.*

---

Hope I'm right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is completely correct, as he's still alive, use **is**, in the *simple present*.  For a person no longer living, use **was**, which is *simple past*.  Here "born" is an adjective describing what kind of leader Ali is or was, an expansion of **He is a leader**.  It has the same meaning and grammar as "natural leader".

However, as "born" is also a verb, you can also say **He was born a leader**, which is *past perfect* because the birth was in the past, an expansion of **He was born**.  This is the same grammar as "He was born a prince."

Comment: Just to add, "Ali is a great manager. He was born a leader.", says even before he became a manager he was already potentially ready to be a great one.  You could also add more background details, "Ali is a great manager. He was a born leader, ever since playschool he's been like that." [literally the first time after birth he might "lead" he showed it].  "Ali is a great manager. He was a born leader." by itself, sounds a bit odd (it makes people wonder what is behind the "born" statement)....

Comment: ...   However people also use "born" loosely to mean , well, lots of things beyond grammer and syntax considerations, e.g. fated, or "he's a natural", or whatever.